# VLC / libvlc free memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, vlc, libvlc

I have some trouble with releasing memory allocated by VLCs libvlc. (http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/index.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vlc/vlc.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    libvlc_instance_t * inst;

    inst = libvlc_new (0, NULL);

    libvlc_release (inst);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with: `gcc -o tvlc tvlc.c -lvlc`

Valgrind says, that there are still 32 non-freed bytes. But I don't know any other way to free the memory, consumed by vlc.

My second problem is with freeing an array which I passed to the vlc-method `libvlc_media_new_path`.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vlc/vlc.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    libvlc_instance_t * inst;
    libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
    libvlc_media_t *m;

    char *path = "/home/Musik/test.mp3";
    char songpath[ strlen(path) +1 ];
    memcpy(songpath, path, strlen(path) +1);

    inst = libvlc_new (0, NULL);

    m = libvlc_media_new_path (inst, songpath);

    mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media (m);

    libvlc_media_release (m);

    libvlc_media_player_release (mp);

    libvlc_release (inst);

    free(songpath);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with: `gcc -o ttvlc ttvlc.c -lvlc`

As soon as I try to free the pointer `songpath`, the program crashes:

> invalid pointer: 0x00007fff4dd76f90

If I do not free the memory, it won"t crash. Can anybody give me a hint what's wrong?

Comment: For the second part, you didn't `malloc()` the memory you are trying to `free()` ("songpath"), it's 'allocated' on the heap. You don't `free()` heap/stack memory, it gets reclaimed when your method exits.

Comment: Wow, actually that was pretty obvious. But thanks a lot, I couldn't spot the error.